# Is there any library that can allow me to view PDFs and add custom right-click options?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf

I need to create a custom PDF viewer and have to create some custom options on right-click. Can any library help me with that? I will also need the coordinates of the right click to help with those options.

Comment: "*Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow*". You can probably ask this on **https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com** but please read their [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336) and [help pages](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting

Comment: PDF.js is complete viewer plugin runing in browser (default in Firefox), there is a gh-pages branch with self cotained WebPack build (aprox. 3 files to get it running ?) and you can adjust JScript somehow, but PDF is quite complex, so not easy to work with. Anyway there is a text-layer (SPANs ? with text in page/-s DIV), that are bit easier to work with.